# finding nearest record by time in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, find

The following code works but doesn't seem very ruby-like so I am looking for a better way to achieve the same.

```
#Grab the events from the page 
  events = page.events.sort_by{|e| e.start_time}

  upcoming = []
  past = []

  events.each do |e|
    if e.start_time >= Time.now
      upcoming.push(e)
    end
    if e.start_time < Time.now
      past.push(e)
    end
  end

 # show the most nearest event (current events if exist)
 event_to_show = (upcoming.count < 0) ? upcoming.first : past.last
```

Comment: There's something strange with that last line: `upcoming.count` is always >= 0 (so never < 0). Typo?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `partition` method to simplify the code.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001496

```
events = page.events.sort_by(&:start_time)

upcoming, past = events.partition{|e| e.start_time >= Time.now}

event_to_show = (upcoming.count < 0) ? upcoming.first : past.last
```